# Video preview plays at old frame rate after changing it

Tags: video-sequence-editor

How I found this problem:

- First, I opened Blender.
- Then, I opened the "Video sequence editor."
- Since I knew I would be working with videos at 60FPS, I changed the frame rate from 24 to 60 FPS in the sidebar.
- Then, I dragged in my first video, and the audio and video lined up correctly (since I changed the frame rate).
- I made a new view thingy to put the preview in by dragging from the bottom left corner of the screen, and I set it to "preview."
- Then, I dragged the "end" slider at the bottom until it lined up with the end of the video, so I could see the whole thing.

Now, here's the problem. When I press play, the video preview plays back really slow (at 24FPS) while the audio is fine. Furthermore, when I pan the video to play back at a different point, the preview *starts* at the correct point, but plays back too slowly.

How can I fix this, so that the video plays at the correct speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you were using a HD video source. AFAIK, Sequencer still works with single thread and not so much effective, relatively speaking. In that case, [**Proxy**](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Sequencer/Usage#Proxy_Strip_Properties_Panel) is born to well solve such issue.

1. Select the video strip you want to make proxy for, toggle **Proxy/Timecode** on the property sidebar;
2. **Menu** > **Strip** > **Rebuild Proxy and Timecode Intices**;
3. on Preview window sidebar, Switch the **Proxy render size** to the expected proxy percentage, which is just generated. As shown below:

[image]

Since the video quality would be significantly reduced, the playback speed is quite faster than the original source. However, VSE still uses original source for final rendering.

---

Another way to keep the video/audio sync while playing preview is to use the suitable playback sync mode, which locates on **Timeline** header. (*AV Sync* or *Frame Dropping*)

[image]

Of course, you can use the above tricks all together to keep the sync best. However, if the playback is still slow or not sync enough, then you'd better turn to a higher performance PC for that. :)

Comment: Thanks! This made it better, but the video still seems to be falling behind a little, even when the proxy thing is at 25%. Is there any way I could just make the preview go slower (both audio and video)? I'd rather have a slow motion preview than unsynchronized audio and video.

Comment: @Doorknob I see, try my updated answer. Good luck.